# Binding Timestamp with Hexdump?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, awk, sed

I am running a script which is given below,

```
sudo  hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x\n"' /dev/ttyUSB0  | Many Pipes | gawk '{ print strftime(":: %s"), $0 }'
```

Here the data is being hex dumped with timestamp and its given below,

```
:: 1461680718 ::ED.DATA

:: 1461680718 ::ED.DATA

:: 1461680718 ::ED.DATA

:: 1461680718 ::ED.DATA

:: 1461680718 ::ED.DATA

:: 1461680718 ::ED.DATA

:: 1461680719 ::ED.DATA
```

As you can see the time doesn't change for all the packets. I think that is because I am dumping the data rather than doing read line. Is there any way to script and make sure I get different value for each packet (in seconds)

Answer (score 0):

The same time comes from buffering. Try to find the command which buffers in the in the queue  and 
try the command [`unbuffer`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unbuffer1.html).

Comment: I tried stdbuf ( i am using raspberry pi wheezy os ), and that did not work !

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following on a jessie pi and had no problem with `stdbuf -oL` in front of hexdump working as intended.

```
while sleep .5;do echo -n x;done |
stdbuf -oL hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x\n"' |
ts %.s |
cat
```

The `while` is to simulate slow input, `ts` timestamps each line, and the `cat` is just to provide another pipe. The output is regular and the timestamps differ by about .5 seconds, after the first 2 lines. The `ts` command is from the `moreutils` package.

Try using `stdbuf -oL` on each of your commands in the pipe.